# Pipe a script path to bash and propagate arguments

Tags: bash, arguments

I'm trying to make an alias to a binary to ensure I'm using the latest version. Though I'm unable to propagate arguments

I'd to call it like so: `script --arg first-argument`

```sh
# One-liner splitted into several lines in order to make it more intelligible
# I consider using `| sort -V | tail -1` to sort, I'm new to `awk` and realize how weak this might be
alias script="ls -alh /path/to/ruby/gems/ | \
              grep -E script-[0-9].[0-9].[0-9]+ | \
              awk 'END{split(\$9,a,\"-\"); print \"/path/to/ruby/gems/script-\"a[2]\"/bin/script\"}' | \
              bash $@"
```

To simplify, the problem would be the same with the following:

```sh
alias script="echo '/path/to/some/script' | bash <arguments>"
```

Hadn't any success with `$@`, `$*`, `"$@"`, `"$*"` or `xargs`, could you help me ?

Answer (score 1):

`alias` appends the arguments by default. If you want to explicitly specify them, use a function.

```
script() {
  ls -alh /path/to/ruby/gems/ |
  grep -E script-[0-9].[0-9].[0-9]+ |
  awk 'END{split(\$9,a,\"-\"); print \"/path/to/ruby/gems/script-\"a[2]\"/bin/script\"}' |
  bash "$@"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, it's never too late to learn about bash functions I guess...! I'm still trying, though your suggestion (minus the " after `$@`) returns `bash: --arg: invalid option`

Comment: @Sumak One `"` was missing. Anyways, the error `--arg: invalid option` is caused when you call `script --arg` because `--arg` is not an option for `bash`. Could it be that you actually want to execute `bash /path/to/ruby/gems/... "$@"` instead of `echo /path/to/ruby/gems/... | bash "$@"`?